# How can I set up Virtual Hosts in Centos7?

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I am trying to set up virtual hosts in Centos7. I followed this guide:

http://twohlix.com/2011/05/setting-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos/

however I keep getting the following error:

```
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' `for details.`
```

the relevant output from journalctrl is as follows:

```
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 17 14:21:54 [8235]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release
Aug 17 14:21:54 [1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 14:21:54 [1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

I cannot figure out what this can be. I have also tried to use a different method whereby the VirtualHost container is inside the httpd.conf file but still no luck. I am using the following configuration.

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jul 23 2014 14:48:00
```

I have not configured DNS etc could this have an impact on it? This is the only other thing I could think of. Any help would be much appreciated I have spent the last couple of days trying to figure out what this could be but everything I tried failed.

Comment: Have a look in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Comment: Note that the config file has changed in v2.4. The document you referred to was for CentOS 6, which used `apache` v2.2.

Comment: @garethTheRed thanks but all I can find is for centos6 or equivalent. can you please suggest an updated guide and/or would know how to do it in centos7? thanks

Comment: no errors in Apache's log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a minimal config for a basic virtual host.  Create a new config file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` and name it (for example) after your domain.  It has to end in `.conf` though:

```
# nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/example.net.conf

<VirtualHost example.net:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure there's viewable content in `/var/www/example.net`

Reload your webserver:

```
# systemctl reload httpd
```

Make sure you have `example.net` resolvable to your host's IP from the client and test.  Any errors should be in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but it still not working plus I do not get anything in the error log the only thing I get is Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

Comment: All solved now thanks for the help! I am not sure exactly what it was but it works! I will finish the work I'm doing now and hopefully I'll include a comprehensive guide on how to do thins in Cento7 shortly. Cheers again Gareth!

Answer (score 0):

Take also into account that the default SELinux configuration will prevent your virtual hosts directories from being accessed by httpd. You will need to set the appropriate context for them:

```
# chcon -R -u system_u -r object_r -t httpd_sys_content_t <DocumentRoot>
```

The other option is to disable SELinux.