# apache Virtual Host Configuration CentOS7

Tags: centos, symlink, apache-httpd

My host machine is Windows 7 and guest machine is CentOS 7. I am a new to Apache and I am trying to create VirtualHost on CentOS7. I have read a lot of documentation and a lot of answers over StackCommunity ([apache symlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks))[virual host CentOS7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150645/how-can-i-set-up-virtual-hosts-in-centos7) and on. Here is what I did.
My `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file configuration without adding any changes to it:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

ServerName localhost
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride None
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
#
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""     combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

<IfModule logio_module>
# You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio

</IfModule>CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

I added index.html to `/var/www/html` with such content:

```
<html>
<title> The library </title>
<body>
<h2> Welcome to our library </h2>
<br /> <hr> <br />
<img width = "600" height = "400" src = "images/library.jpg">
<body/>
</html>
```

Then I created symbol link for `/var/www/html/index.html` in `/var/www/my_host/my_host.html`

> `ln -s /var/www/html/index.html /var/www/html/my_host.html`

Next step: I created `my_host.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` and allow **Symlink**:

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/my_host.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.my_host.com
ServerAlias *.my_host.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/my_host
<Directory "/var/www/my_host">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/www/my_host/error_log
LogFormat "%a %v %p %U %m %T" common_new_format
CustomLog /var/www/my_host/custom_log common_new_format
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I checked apache with this command: `apachectl configtest` and got output => `Syntax OK`.
After all this steps I started httpd:

> `systemctl start httpd`

Everything started perfectly.

But there was one problem I got in error_log of my virtual host:

`AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/my_host/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

I understand that I can add `DirectoryIndex my_host.html` to my `my_host.conf` file but why my **symlink** `my_host.html -> ../html/index.html` did not work as I expected it to be? I thought it would be enough to allow `FollowSymLinks` in my `/var/www/my_host/` directory and I did not need to point another `DirectoryIndex` ? My question is: Why does `FollowSymLinks` is not enough to point `DirectoryIndex` if I have already add symbol link to index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're reading too much into the symlink. `httpd` will not look if you have files that are symlinks to files that are called `index.html` in either case. It looks for a file named `index.html` in your DocumentRoot.

The `FollowSymLinks` is needed when such a file exists and is a symlink. (Imagine if, by accident or malice, a symlink to say, `/etc/passwd` or your private SSH key ended up in your DocumentRoot!)

Comment: But if I want to add symlink in my `/var/www/` directory for another directory that is located in my home directory for example - can I use `FollowSymLinks` in this way?

Comment: Yes, but the "relevant name" that will be part of the URL is the name of the symlink, not the name of its target.

Comment: Oh!Now I understand!